# Не могу добавить interop зависимость 2гис в проект VisualSturio c# - "Не является сборкой .Net"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, 2gis-api

Есть проект который использует 2gis интероп - для поиска улиц и т.д.
Раньше прекрасно добавлялось в проект зависимость grym.exe Но сейчас не хочет, по каким то причинам.

Пишет - Не удалось добавить ссылку на "путь..\grym.exe" Не удается зарегистрировать библиотеку типов ActiveX "путь..\grym.exe\1". Не является сборкой .Net.

Причем раньше все работало..
Я просто ставил
"Внедрить типы взаимодействия"
"Изолированный "
"Копировать локально"

в false.

Но сейчас не дает именно добавить как ссылку... Что может быть?

Comment: Версия дотнета какая?

Comment: Версия дотнета - еще фреймворк - 4.8

Comment: Выглядит, что пытаетесь нативную как управляемую подключить, разве обычных [DllImport] не достаточно?

Comment: Даже не dll а .exe

Comment: exe не является библиотекой